# SVG rendering issues in chrome for tiny elements

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg

I am making an interactive map in SVG, to be used in a browser, however, there are rendering differences between the browsers, which makes small elements display really badly in Chrome. I have attached some screenshots and a sample link to illustrate my issue:

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Firefox/IE:

[image: Firefox and IE]

You can also [click here](http://suldashi.com/sample.svg) to see a live sample. Is there any way to make Chrome render like Firefox or IE in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` to your svg eleement. Chrome makes different anti-aliasing choices for drawing than Firefox/Safari - so very small features can get anti-aliased out. You can remove anti-aliasing with crispEdges and then they (generally) all look the same - at the cost of some pixelation.